# Im wondering how to add existing files to my github repository, even if i already have items there

Tags: c#, github, replit

I am in a computer programming and algorithms class, we set up and account on repl.it, and github. Then she told us to use the terminal in repl.it her instructions were.

```
git remote add origin (your repository URL)
git push -u origin master
put in user name and password
git add file or . for all
git commit -a -m 'stuff'
git push
add username and password
```

But when doing this i run in to various problems. I have done research into some of them such as it failing to push some refs, or it refusing to merge unrelated histories. But i've basically fixed that now. But every-time i go through the process of,

```
git add ., git commit "Name", git push origin master --force.
```

It ends up just replacing the existing document i had. Not adding the new one. I need to add all of my coding projects to github for grading. But if it keeps replacing them i don't know what to do. Sorry if the question has been asked before, but i didn't see any related ones.

Answer (score 0):

Some points in your question are not clear to me. I'll try to explain some things anyway.

With this command you connect your local git folder with a remote repository.

```
git remote add origin (your repository URL)
```

---

Here we are pushing to the remote repository.
'-u' is shorthand for '--set-upstream', that connects your local 'master' with your remote 'master' branch

```
git push -u origin master
```

---

Add a single file, so it gets tracked. In other words: mark it for the next commit.
This is not pushed right now. Pushing is done with 'git push'

```
git add file
```

---

Be careful with this one. You add everything. It is cleaner to make small commits with changes/files that are related. In other words: one feature one commit, one bug-fix one commit, etc.

```
git add .
```

---

Well, thats redundant. 'git commit -a' adds 'all' changed files and puts them into one commit. '-m' is handy for writing the commit message directly in your console.

```
git commit -a -m 'stuff'
```

---

Pushes every commit to your remote repository

```
git push
```

---

The (properly) **bad** thing!(!!). Really. Dont. Do. This.
The [git docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push) explain it pretty good:

> "git push --force" is a method reserved for a case where you do mean to lose history.

and

> "This flag disables these checks, and can cause the remote repository to lose commits; use it with care."

```
git push origin master --force
```

I guess you used `force` because you had a merge conflict? Solve it, dont just ignore the warning and `--force` it to ignore those checks.

---

You said ...

"It ends up just replacing the existing document i had"
Maybe because of you where using the '--force' flag. I would need an exact example, so just a guess.

"Not adding the new one."
Try something out, just to understand it:

  add a file.txt (not with git add, add it to the folder)

  in your console type 'git status' that shows every change you did. The new file should be seen as 'new but not tracked'

  now type 'git add file.txt'

  again type 'git status'. now the file should be seen as 'tracked and added'

  if you now typed 'git commit -m "added file.txt"' you would create a commit and add that file into the commit

  if you would 'git push' now, the newly created file gets pushed to your remote repo

---

Git is soooo powerful. Learn it, even if the beginning is hard, it is worth it!
Read up the documents your teacher (hopefuly) handed out and/or read up online tutorials.
Git gets more and more mandatory.

Comment: Okay thank you, you're right, it was giving me merge conflicts. I was trying to solve my problem for like 3 hours before i asked, but your right. I will attempt to solve it. Thank you for the detailed response.